# Looking for a sitemap generator

Tags: sitemap

I am looking for a good way to generate a sitemap for my current site. I inherited a huge site at work and we are going to start the process of IA analysis and redesign. It would be awesome if there was some way to crawl the site and automatically generate a sitemap with all of our pages. Does anyone know of any good resources?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the site running on any kind of CMS? There may be a better platform-specific solution if so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For sitemap generation I use GSiteCrawler it works great and it gives you a lot of additional information. If you're looking to do additional analysis I use Xenu link Sleuth it's main purpose is to help you find broken links but it also gives a lot of IA related info such as depth from the home page, internal links pointing at certain pages etc. Both tools are free.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a free solution... http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

May not be what you are looking for but it saves you from coding a script to do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I already hit them up, but having more than 500 pages made it not a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "xml sitemap generator" found [plenty of resources](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=xml+sitemap+generator).

Answer (score 0):

Is the website running PHP?

I made a PHP script for myself some time ago. Let a comment if is the case and I give the 4shared link.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Microsys A1 Sitemap Generator](http://www.microsystools.com/products/sitemap-generator/), it crawls your website and shows potential problems like broken links, duplicate content, duplicate titles, everything you need to know to make your website better. And then when everything is fixed it creates a sitemap with a click of a button.

Answer (score 0):

For $4 I got a PHP script from Code Canyon (http://codecanyon.net/item/php-site-map-and-google-sitemap/49131) and it will automatically update your sitemap. I also added a line to my .htaccess file so /sitemap.php will be rewritten to /sitemap.xml. If you want to take it one step further, you can find PHP scripts that will automatically ping search engines with your new sitemap, although Google and Bing are the only search engines left that let users ping the websites and their spiders can crawl websites daily.