# Free unlimited-page sitemap generator?

Tags: seo, sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a sitemap generator](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/looking-for-a-sitemap-generator)

I have been using www.xml-sitemaps.com/ but their limit is 500 pages.  My site has grown beyond that and I am wondering whether there is another tool I can use that I can use to create sitemaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are recommended by Google: http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

Answer (score 0):

also FreeSitemapGenerator is nice, though it can be slow if you have thousands of pages.