# How do I make a free sitemap.xml for a site that is few thousand pages?

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free unlimited-page sitemap generator?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/11625/free-unlimited-page-sitemap-generator)

Is there a free tool out there that would let me make a free sitemap for about 3k page site?

Thanks!

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried it with that many pages, but this program has worked well for me.

GSiteCrawler
http://gsitecrawler.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**[xSitemap.com](http://www.xsitemap.com/)**

but for professional services **[Unlimited Sitemap Generator](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/standalone-google-sitemap-generator.html)** try this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it for a once-off job for XML/image/video/whatever sitemaps, you could use the trial version of A1 Sitemap Generator. (Otherwise, GSiteCrawler is a good suggestion.)