# online site map generator that has an access via URL

Tags: sitemap, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a sitemap generator](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/looking-for-a-sitemap-generator)

I am looking for a service that I can access daily based to generate a sitemap.xml file for SEO.

Something like
http://www.seo-sitemap-service.com?freq=daily&generate-for-url=http://www.mysite.com

Answer (score 3):

Try this : [Sitemap Generator](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)

Comment: Thanks, but I cant really have a daily cron that takes the data once a day, I need to manually generate that, download and upload...

Comment: but they do have a premium account. check that out, you may get some api help.